# Simple Gradle project with Tomcat plugin doesn't work

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle

I have the following problem - I created a simple Gradle project named "spring" with `com.bmuschko.tomcat` plugin. But when I run Gradle build and `tomcatRun` tasks and enter http://localhost:8080/spring, I get 404 error. Certainly, I get no error messages during build and server startup. There is build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

group 'training'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    def tomcatVersion = '9.0.17'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:9.0.0.M6",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}"
}

tomcat {
    httpProtocol = 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol'
    ajpProtocol  = 'org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNio2Protocol'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.5'
    }
}
```

I have also one jsp file named `hello.jsp` put in `src/main/webapp`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Hello Gradle Web App</title>
</head>
<body>

<jsp:useBean id="greeting" class="test.Test"/>

<h3>${greeting.hello}</h3>

</body>
</html>
```

and `Test.java` file put in `src/main/java/test`:

```
package test;

public class Test {
    public String getHello() {
        return "Hello Spring!";
    }
}
```

As you can see, server seems to be starting successfully:

```
17:46:12: Executing tasks 'build tomcatRun'...

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :war UP-TO-DATE
> Task :assemble UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test NO-SOURCE
> Task :check UP-TO-DATE
> Task :build UP-TO-DATE
> Task :tomcatRun
Started Tomcat Server
The Server is running at http://localhost:8080/spring
```

Comment: What's the name of the JSP file?

Comment: @thokuest it's "hello.jsp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your JSP file is name `hello.jsp`.

The Tomcat documentation (`conf/web.xml`) states the following:

> ==================== Default Welcome File List =====================
>
> When a request URI refers to a directory, the default servlet looks
>   for a "welcome file" within that directory and, if present, to the
>   corresponding resource URI for display.
>   If no welcome files are present, the default servlet either serves a
>   directory listing (see default servlet configuration on how to
>   customize) or returns a 404 status, depending on the value of the
>   listings setting.

The default welcome files are:

- index.html
- index.htm, and
- index.jsp

So what does that mean?

When you point your browser to http://localhost:8080/spring, there's no specific page listed in the request URL. Tomcat, as well as other web servers, still try to deliver a page so that the browser can display something. By default, if no page is specified in the URL, the default home page is delivered. As your file is named `hello.jsp`, it is not considered a welcome file, thus Tomcat delivers the 404 error.

You can fix the issue by

- Pointing your browser to http://localhost:8080/spring/hello.jsp
- Renaming `hello.jsp` to `index.jsp`
- Customizing `welcome-file-list` in your `web.xml` to include `hello.jsp`

That being said, the issue is not with the `com.bmuschko.tomcat` plugin nor your build file.